# How to hide element with css in between the same class

Tags: css, sass

Groups of elements are separeted by elements without class `class-collapse`. I want to hide elements between first, last of `class-collapse` type.
I have tried `:first-of-type` and `last-of-type` with `display: block;` and `class-collapse` with `display: none;` but it does'nt work, olso `class-collapse ~ class-collapse` does'nt work either.

```
<div class="class-collapse">div1</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div2</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div3</div>
<div class="other-class">div4</div>
<div class="other-class">div5</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div6</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div7</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div8</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div9</div>
<div class="other-class">div10</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div11</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div12</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div13</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div14</div>
```

expected result:

```
<div class="class-collapse">div1</div>
<!-- removed divs 2 -->
<div class="class-collapse">div3</div>
<div class="other-class">div4</div>
<div class="other-class">div5</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div6</div>
<!-- removed divs 7 8 -->
<div class="class-collapse">div9</div>
<div class="other-class">div10</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div11</div>
<!-- removed divs 12 13 -->
<div class="class-collapse">div14</div>
```

How to implement this result in css?

Comment: is using javacript an option?

Comment: If there is no option without it Yes. But I think there is a way to do this only in css, scss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add another class to the first and last element like the following.

```css
div.do-not-hide{

  display: block;
}

.class-collapse {

  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-collapse do-not-hide">div1</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div2</div>
<div class="class-collapse do-not-hide">div3</div>
<div class="other-class">div4</div>
<div class="other-class">div5</div>
<div class="class-collapse do-not-hide">div6</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div7</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div8</div>
<div class="class-collapse do-not-hide">div9</div>
<div class="other-class">div10</div>
<div class="class-collapse do-not-hide">div11</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div12</div>
<div class="class-collapse">div13</div>
<div class="class-collapse do-not-hide">div14</div>
```

Comment: You need to add `do-not-hide` to div3, div6, div9 and div11, too.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Updated the answer.

Comment: So simple, I think I can check in array if previous index is collapse or not and if next one is collapse than I can define if it is first element of group and last and I can implement this solution. But this solution requires some logic in template.